# JNativeHook changes keyboard language

Tags: java, keyboard, hook, native

I recently needed a way to create global hook for key events in a java application. JNativeHook was a really nice solution, the [jar](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/downloads/list) file i downloaded from their SVN repo worked immediately without messing around with the native source.

BUT i have a really small, but still undesirable issue: When the global hook is added, the keyboard language changes to english (EN) from my default hungarian (HU).

I looked at the examples on their Wiki, but i have found nothing. My code is pretty simple, taken from their example:

```
try 
{
    GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
} 
catch (NativeHookException ex) 
{
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}

//KeyHandler class implements the NativeKeyListener interface
GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
```

(I'm using it on Windows 7 64bit)

So my question is: **Is there a way to keep the default keyboard language without modifying, and recompiling the native source?**

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar issue reported to the [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/issues/detail?id=70&can=1).  If this is still an problem, please reopen the bug.

> The language on Windows will
>   change to the default locale when a new application starts.  For
>   example on my Windows 7 machine, English:US is set as the default
>   locale (shortcut ctrl+0) and German:DE set as the secondary (shortcut
>   ctrl + 1).  When a new application lunches, it will set that
>   applications locale to EN:US, the locale can then be changed back to
>   German:DE with ether the shortcut or the language bar.  The
>   JNativeHook library appears to handle this correctly.  If you are
>   still having an issue, please reopen this ticket and provide
>   additional information.